# cpan install of DBD::mysql failing on tests and symbol not found. OSX Mojave

Tags: perl, cpan, macos-mojave, dbd-mysql

This looks like it's been around for years - but I can't find anything recent and related to Mac, and dealing only with just installing the CPAN module DBD::mysql I've been trawling the internet for days now...

```
#   Failed test 'use DBD::mysql;'
#   at t/00base.t line 15.
#     Tried to use 'DBD::mysql'.
#     Error:  Can't load '/Users/robert/.cpanm/work/1542100720.91387/DBD-mysql-4.048/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle' for module DBD::mysql: dlopen(/Users/robert/.cpanm/work/1542100720.91387/DBD-mysql-4.048/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
#   Referenced from: /Users/robert/.cpanm/work/1542100720.91387/DBD-mysql-4.048/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
#   Expected in: flat namespace
#  in /Users/robert/.cpanm/work/1542100720.91387/DBD-mysql-4.048/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle at /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/lib/perl5/5.28.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 197.
# ^@ at t/00base.t line 15.
# Compilation failed in require at t/00base.t line 15.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/00base.t line 15.
Bailout called.  Further testing stopped:  Unable to load DBD::mysql
FAILED--Further testing stopped: Unable to load DBD::mysql
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
-> FAIL Installing DBD::mysql failed. See /Users/robert/.cpanm/work/1542100720.91387/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
```

This is the cpanm line I'm using.

```
sudo cpanm  --configure-args="--libs='-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/lib' --cflags='-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include/mysql -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/include/mysql'" DBD::mysql
```

I have installed mysql with Homebrew, and everything else for that matter. I've even copied a few libs into system directories - but nothing seems to want to get this cpan module to install and work.

**EDIT: Additions after this line. 
Let's try Making the package by hand**

```
sudo perl Makefile.PL --libs="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/lib -lssl -lcrypto"
```

The Result of Make. Looking good. I see no errors here.Apparently all libs are available for compiling.

```
zeus:DBD-mysql-4.048-0 robert$ sudo perl Makefile.PL --libs="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/lib"
I will use the following settings for compiling and testing:

  cflags        (mysql_config ) = -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/include/mysql
  embedded      (guessed      ) = 
  libs          (User's choice) = -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/lib
  mysql_config  (Users choice ) = mysql_config
  nocatchstderr (default      ) = 0
  nofoundrows   (default      ) = 0
  nossl         (default      ) = 0
  testdb        (User's choice) = test
  testhost      (default      ) = 
  testpassword  (default      ) = 
  testport      (default      ) = 
  testsocket    (default      ) = 
  testuser      (User's choice) = root

To change these settings, see 'perl Makefile.PL --help' and
'perldoc DBD::mysql::INSTALL'.

Checking if libs are available for compiling...
Looks good.

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Using DBI 1.642 (for perl 5.028000 on darwin-thread-multi-2level) installed in /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI/
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for DBD::mysql
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
zeus:DBD-mysql-4.048-0 robert$
```

Now let's see if a **make** works.

Looking good. 1 warning about WIDEST_UTYPE but it's only a warning...

Then, mysql.bundle is made

```
chmod 755 blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
Manifying 3 pod documents
```

Ok, now the big test. **make test**.

... and it fails.

```
zeus:DBD-mysql-4.048-0 robert$ sudo make test
"/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- mysql.bs blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bs 644
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00base.t .............................. 1/6 
#   Failed test 'use DBD::mysql;'
#   at t/00base.t line 15.
#     Tried to use 'DBD::mysql'.
#     Error:  Can't load '/Users/robert/.cpan/build/DBD-mysql-4.048-0/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle' for module DBD::mysql: dlopen(/Users/robert/.cpan/build/DBD-mysql-4.048-0/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
#   Referenced from: /Users/robert/.cpan/build/DBD-mysql-4.048-0/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
#   Expected in: flat namespace
#  in /Users/robert/.cpan/build/DBD-mysql-4.048-0/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle at /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/lib/perl5/5.28.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 197.
#  at t/00base.t line 15.
# Compilation failed in require at t/00base.t line 15.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/00base.t line 15.
Bailout called.  Further testing stopped:  Unable to load DBD::mysql
FAILED--Further testing stopped: Unable to load DBD::mysql
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
```

... and there it is. The same error. Now I also tried MariaDB - same result, although slightly different error messages.

What am I missing here.

Comment: Maybe using `DBD::MariaDB` ( https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::MariaDB ) instead works better, although both drivers had recent releases that should address most failures.

Comment: Ok, getting closer. "Can't link/include C library 'ssl', 'crypto', aborting."  looks like I need to point it to the ssl and crypto libraries.

Comment: Got it. Finally done by hand. Shees. See My Answer.

Answer (score 14):

So I finally found it. Of course, it was locating the libraries and include files properly.

So I went into the cpan directory on my system

```
/Users/robert/.cpan/build/DBD-mysql-4.048-0
```

After checking just where the brew installations were for both openssl and mysql, I woke up.

```
sudo perl Makefile.PL --libs="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/lib -lmysqlclient"
```

Now. that worked because after looking in the mysaql lib directory, I see that the library is 'mysqlclient' and not mysql. As you see above.

Now that worked doing the Makefile.PL thing as above.

Then 'make' worked. As above. Not showing any errors... as above

Then **sudo make test worked** - this time.

```
All tests successful.
Files=73, Tests=9, 11 wallclock secs ( 0.24 usr  0.15 sys +  8.25 cusr  1.23 csys =  9.87 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

Finally - make install. Worked

```
zeus:DBD-mysql-4.048-0 robert$ sudo make install
"/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- mysql.bs blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bs 644
Manifying 3 pod documents
Files found in blib/arch: installing files in blib/lib into architecture dependent library tree
Installing /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
Installing /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Bundle/DBD/mysql.pm
Installing /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/mysql.pm
Installing /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.pod
Installing /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/mysql/GetInfo.pm
Installing /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/share/man/man3/Bundle::DBD::mysql.3
Installing /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/share/man/man3/DBD::mysql::INSTALL.3
Installing /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/share/man/man3/DBD::mysql.3
Appending installation info to /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/lib/perl5/5.28.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/perllocal.pod
zeus:DBD-mysql-4.048-0 robert$ pwd
/Users/robert/.cpan/build/DBD-mysql-4.048-0
```

Well finally. Now why did I want this? I can't remember.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Been trying to figure this out for an hour. The install instructions for the module need to be updated and had me trying to get it to work with mysql-connector-c. Your solution worked like a charm, though. Note that you should change the version number in the path from 8.0.12 to 8.0.<whatever>.