# Cannot install DBD::mysql on Mac

Tags: perl, cpan, dbd-mysql

(It's my first time posting here, so the format might not be right, sorry.)
I have been trying to install DBD::mysql on my macOS Catalina using cpan, but I have not succeeded yet. I used perlbrew, and tried mysql and mariaDB, but still no luck. Also, I've looked into different solutions online (Probably messed up a bit as well), but no luck as well, so I want to see if anyone can help. Thanks!

The log is as below:

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7044 on perl 5.030002 built for darwin-2level
Work directory is /Users/tingheithomas/.cpanm/work/1585766734.94805
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have /usr/local/bin/wget
You have /usr/bin/tar: bsdtar 3.3.2 - libarchive 3.3.2 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.0.5 bz2lib/1.0.6
You have /usr/bin/unzip
Searching DBD::mysql () on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on DBD::mysql
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/D/DV/DVEEDEN/DBD-mysql-4.050.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking DBD-mysql-4.050.tar.gz
Entering DBD-mysql-4.050
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have Data::Dumper 0 ... Yes (2.174)
Checking if you have DBI 1.609 ... Yes (1.643)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.58 ... Yes (7.34)
Checking if you have Devel::CheckLib 1.09 ... Yes (1.14)
Configuring DBD-mysql-4.050
Running Makefile.PL


PLEASE NOTE:

For 'make test' to run properly, you must ensure that the
database user 'tingheithomas' can connect to your MySQL server
and has the proper privileges that these tests require such
as 'drop table', 'create table', 'drop procedure', 'create procedure'
as well as others.

mysql> grant all privileges on test.* to 'tingheithomas'@'localhost' identified by 's3kr1t';

You can also optionally set the user to run 'make test' with:

perl Makefile.PL --testuser=username

I will use the following settings for compiling and testing:

  cflags        (mysql_config) = -I/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/include/mysql
  embedded      (mysql_config) = 
  ldflags       (guessed     ) = 
  libs          (mysql_config) = -L/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto
  mysql_config  (guessed     ) = mysql_config
  nocatchstderr (default     ) = 0
  nofoundrows   (default     ) = 0
  nossl         (default     ) = 0
  testdb        (default     ) = test
  testhost      (default     ) = 
  testpassword  (default     ) = 
  testport      (default     ) = 
  testsocket    (default     ) = 
  testuser      (guessed     ) = tingheithomas

To change these settings, see 'perl Makefile.PL --help' and
'perldoc DBD::mysql::INSTALL'.

Checking if libs are available for compiling...
Can't link/include C library 'ssl', 'crypto', aborting.
-> N/A
-> FAIL Configure failed for DBD-mysql-4.050. See /Users/tingheithomas/.cpanm/work/1585766734.94805/build.log for details.
```

Comment: See also [this](https://github.com/perl5-dbi/DBD-mysql/issues/216) issue, and [cpan install of DBD::mysql failing on tests and symbol not found. OSX Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53277884/2173773)

Comment: There is also more information on the installation procedure in [DBD::mysql::INSTALL](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql::INSTALL)

Comment: Do you have libssl and libcrypto installed? Including the header files? (These are usually found in a separate `dev` or `devel` package when using a package manager.)

Comment: Thanks Hakon Hægland! I read the tutorial before and didn't work before. Now it's finally working after a second try! I can finally go to bed early today after staying up till 3am for two nights. You made my day!