# Perl Module Installation Mac OSX Gatekeeper

Tags: macos, perl, osx-gatekeeper

i can not install perl modules on my mac. The problem seems to be Gatekeeper.
when modules contain binary libs (*.bundle) those libs have to be codesigned to be accepted by Gatekeeper. with the normal

perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
make install

i don't get a valid codesigned bundle/lib. should it not work out of the box?
i get the following error

```
t/pullparser.t ....... Can't load '~/.cpan/build/HTML-Parser-3.73-0/blib/arch/auto/HTML/Parser/Parser.bundle' for module HTML::Parser: dlopen(~/.cpan/build/HTML-Parser-3.73-0/blib/arch/auto/HTML/Parser/Parser.bundle, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    ~/.cpan/build/HTML-Parser-3.73-0/blib/arch/auto/HTML/Parser/Parser.bundle: code signature in (~/.cpan/build/HTML-Parser-3.73-0/blib/arch/auto/HTML/Parser/Parser.bundle) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed. at
```

Comment: See also [Installing Perl Module on Mac OSX Catalina - code signing binary libs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63600676/2173773)

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac, I always install modules using cpan or perl-shell.

Try this out:

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
install HTML::Parser
```

Or

```
cpan install HTML::Parser
```