# DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable is not forwarded to external command in Makefile on macOS

Tags: linux, macos, makefile, macos-catalina

I am debugging some test failures (`make test`) for a Perl module on macOS. I discovered that the problem seems to be that the environment variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not forwarded to an external command run from within the `Makefile`. Here is a minimal example:

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    @echo $$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

On Linux from the Bash shell, I can do (or rather replace `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which is used for this purpose on Linux):

```
$ export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=bar
$ make
bar
```

However, if I run the same `Makefile` on macOS Catalina 10.15.5, the variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is empty:

```
$ export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=bar
$ make
# [No output]
```

Any idea what is the reason for this difference?

Comment: Environment variables don't need to be specifically forwarded. Child processes inherit them automatically (and `make` doesn't do anything to disable this behaviour). I would suspect that the `$$` syntax doesn't work in macos make, but the freebsd man page shows it should. I don't have macos to test. What does `@echo '$$FOO'` (with single quotes) show?

Comment: It shows `$FOO`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior on macOS Mojave with the default `make` (GNU make 3.81). What is the default make on Catalina (`make --version`)?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet It shows GNU make 3.81. And it works here too with `$FOO`, my bad. But it does not work if I replace `FOO` with `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (which was my original variable, I thought I tested that it didn't work with `FOO` also but apparently I did not). Updated question

Comment: You forgot to edit the last `FOO` in your question. Anyway, I tested with `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` on macOS Mojane and GNU make 3.81 and I still cannot reproduce your problem: `make` prints `bar` on the standard output.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Thanks, I have updated question hope it is correct now. So this is then something that was introduced in Catalina? (I double checked and I still get empty output)

Comment: You are probably suffering from this: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/RuntimeProtections/RuntimeProtections.html - if you try to set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `bash` note that it takes no effect.

Comment: @Oo.oO Thanks for the link! That seems to be the reason yes..

Comment: @Oo.oO Yes, that must be it. I disabled system integrity protection long time ago and completely forgot about it.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Do you know for which version of macOS this protection was introduced?

Comment: @HåkonHægland El Capitan, if I remember well.