# Perl - dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_init

Tags: perl

I'm encountering a message seen for the first time when I execute a perl script requiring DBD::mysql module.

Simple example:

```
use DBI;
 
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:db",'root','root');

$dbh->disconnect();
```

I'm working on macOS 11.1 on ARM64, my perl version is 5.30.3 installed with perlbrew.

The message is:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_init
  Referenced from: /Users/test/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.3/lib/site_perl/5.30.3/darwin-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_init
  Referenced from: /Users/test/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.3/lib/site_perl/5.30.3/darwin-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

Abort trap: 6
```

Any idea how this can be fixed?

In my `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` I've added these lines:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:${PATH}"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227008/discussion-on-question-by-flavio-del-grosso-perl-dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-fai).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved installing mysql natively. I reinstalled it using brew and passing `-s` to the command (`brew install -s mysql`). So the problem was the wrong architecture and recompiling it for ARM64 now also `make test` while installing DBD::mysql works well without any error.

Hope can helps :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the new [system integrity protection procedure](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/RuntimeProtections/RuntimeProtections.html), which causes `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` not to be propagated to sub processes. Specifically, when running `make test` the test subprocess does not pick up the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` from the parent shell.

The issue has been [reported](https://github.com/perl5-dbi/DBD-mysql/issues/322) previously.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63629878/2173773) question.